# Gradle Espresso - Task connectedProductFlavorBuildTypeAndroidTest not found in root project

Tags: android, gradle, android-espresso

My build.gradle is like this:

```
productFlavors {
        mainFlavor {
            // ...
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
             // ...
        }
        buildType1 {// I write mock data classes for Espresso tests here
             // ...
        }
    }
```

`./gradlew tasks` includes `connectedMainFlavorDebugAndroidTest` but not `connectedMainFlavorBuildType1AndroidTest`.
Why?

I want to specifically run Espresso tests for **buildType1** only.
I'm not the owner of the project, I'm not allowed to use either `mainFlavorDebug` or `someNewFlavorDebug` to write Espresso tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips.html#change-the-test-build-type):

> By default, all tests run against the debug build type. You can change
>   this to another build type by using the testBuildType property in your
>   module-level build.gradle file. For example, if you want to run your
>   tests against your "staging" build type, edit the file as shown in the
>   following snippet.
>
> android {
>       ...
>       testBuildType "staging" }